# How do I make this work? (applescript)

Tags: variables, applescript, identification

Hello I am trying to make this code work but after Blurb is executed it says it doesn't know Blob. So I thought that I just had to put Blob at the beginning but the Blob doesn't know Blurb and so on. 
Order if all answers are correct is Blob, Blurb, Blirb, Blorb, Blarb, and finish.

```
script finish
set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
    "Can you escape?" buttons "Cool!"
end script

script Blarb
set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
    "Can you escape?" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
if button returned of dialogResult = "Yes" then
    run script Blob
end if
end script

script Blorb
set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
    "Can you escape?" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
if button returned of dialogResult = "No" then
    run script Blob
else if button returned of dialogResult = "Yes" then
    run script Blarb
end if
end script

script Blirb
set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
    "Can you escape?" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
if button returned of dialogResult = "No" then
    run script Blob
else if button returned of dialogResult = "Yes" then
    run script Blorb
end if
end script

script Blurb
set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
    "Can you escape?" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
if button returned of dialogResult = "Yes" then
    run script Blob
else if button returned of dialogResult = "No" then
    run script Blirb
end if
end script

script Blob
set Variable to "No"
repeat while Variable = "No"
    set dialogResult to display dialog ¬
        "Can you escape" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
    set Variable to button returned of dialogResult
    if button returned of dialogResult = "Yes" then
        run script Blurb
    end if
end repeat
end script



run script Blob --Order if all answers are correct is Blob, Blurb, Blirb, Blorb, Blarb, and finish.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. General advice: don't use `run script NAME`; `run NAME` is sufficient here. (`run script` creates a whole new AS interpreter instance, and sends the script off to be run in that.) It'll also let you see exactly where the error is occurring.
2. The problem here is that the AppleScript compiler is a piece of crap. Statically-bound variable names need to be declared *before* code that uses them, or else the compiler's too dumb to find and bind them correctly. If practical, reorder your script objects so that they are declared above code that uses them. That won't work if you've got circular references where script A refers script B and B refers to A, however. Inserting a `my` keyword before the variable name makes AS look up that variable dynamically instead, avoiding this particular problem. (Calls to AS subroutines are always dynamically bound, so you don't need to worry about those.)
3. Don't post example code that requires people to force-quit Script Editor to get out of it. It's annoying and won't make you any friends.

Comment: OK, sorry, I am a noob to applescript so I will search up how to use the "my" keyword.

Comment: Change all `run script Blob` commands to `run my Blob`, `run script Blirb` to `run my Blirb`, etc.

Comment: Oh, and learn to use AppleScript for Good, not Evil. Honestly, it's evil enough as it is.

Comment: this isn't evil it's like a sort of combination code